# What to use for a simple, local, single-user wiki/confluence type of application?

Tags: ios, wiki

On a Mac system I want to use an application which allows me to create wiki/confluence like pages (with markup, like in a wiki or confluence page), to write down notes, create pages, connect these pages internally, add links to external content, use tables, and images.

This application should be simple to install, and is only for a single user, with the data (pages) stored locally.

What do you recommend?

I tried [DocuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/) but the installation instructions does not seem to work, and I had a look at [TiddlyWiki](https://tiddlywiki.com/), but I got really confused when the Download section is asking to choose a method for saving changes. No text editor every asked me to choose a method for saving changes!

So is there something more useable out there?

Comment: The question is tagged ios even though it's about Mac, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try TiddlyWiki again.

I just tried installing it in Firefox but it supports most browsers. First I installed the extension, then ran the binary from [Timimi](https://github.com/ibnishak/Timimi/releases) in Terminal. I had to make it executable first.

Something like:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x timimi-2-1-1-Mac
./timimi-2-1-1-Mac
```

Then it asks you which browser you use and installs itself.

The system asked me to allow access to the file system the first time I tried saving but then it worked. So a little convoluted but it is functioning.

Comment: I followed your steps, took a look in the README, but now what? Where is that Wiki now? Where to navigate the browser to? This extremely important information seems to be missing from any docs!

Comment: You need to download an empty wiki by clicking Download Empty from https://tiddlywiki.com/#GettingStarted . Open this in your browser. There you can edit and save thanks to the extension.